# Redux form, initializing a form from state

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I'm attempting to integrate this example into my application:

http://redux-form.com/6.5.0/examples/initializeFromState/

Unfortunately I can't seem to get it to work. I've had to change a couple of things to make it fit my application needs, so the most notable changes are that rather than passing an action object into `connect()` I'm passing a function that returns an action. Additionally, my syntax for mapping state to properties is slightly different, but should yield the same result.

What puzzles me the most, though is how is it going to know what properties of tag (retrieved from redux) are mapping to what form fields?

I can't really figure out "what" is going to trigger the form being initialized. Is it the connect method?

Any suggestions what I may try to get this to work?

```
// edit.js

import React from 'react';
import { Field, reduxForm, initialize } from 'redux-form'
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchTag } from '../../actions/tags-actions';
import { updateTag } from '../../actions/tags-actions';
import EditTagForm from '../../components/edit-tag-form';

class EditTag extends React.Component {

  EditTagForm = reduxForm({
    form: 'editTagForm'
  })(EditTagForm);

  handleSubmit(values) {
    const tag = {
      "name": values.tagName,
      "disambiguation": values.tagDisambiguation,
      "status": values.status || "published",
      "domain": "some_domain", // @todo hardcoded
      "type": values.tagType || "Person"
    };
    this.props.dispatch(updateTag(tag));
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>{this.props.tag.name}</p>
        <EditTagForm onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}/>
      </div>
    );
  };
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  tag: { ...state.tags.tags[0] },
  fetching: state.tags.fetching,
  fetched: state.tags.fetched,
  error: state.tags.error,
  initialValues: { ...state.tags.tags[0] }
});

// @todo fetching a hardcoded tag
export default connect(mapStateToProps, fetchTag("237171c8-bc6b-498b-abbf-99a595d6442d"))(EditTag);

// tags-actions.js

...

export function fetchTag(uuid) {
    return function(dispatch) {
      api.getTagFromUuid([uuid], {})
        .then((response) => {
          dispatch({type: "FETCH_TAGS_FULFILLED", payload: {
            tags: [response.body]
          }});
        })
        .catch((req) => {
          dispatch({type: "FETCH_TAGS_REJECTED", payload: { response: req.response }});
        });
    };
}

...
```

Comment: Properties of `initialValues` = `name` attribute of `Field` component

Comment: Did you find an answer to this @funkylaundry ? I have a similar issue.